# 'ng new appname' is not work properly in angular 7

Tags: angular7, angular7-router

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5iX5.png)My angular cli is not working properly and when I create a new app then it's not completely run.
C:\Users\ashu>ng new appname
? Would you like to add Angular routing? (y/N)
C:\Users\ashu>ng new appname
? Would you like to add Angular routing? (y/N)
C:\Users\ashu>

Answer (score 0):

It seems like angular installation is not proper.

Remove angular 7 completely using
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean

& again install it using

npm install -g @angular/cli@wished.version.here

Best of luck.